# Image urls on remote server

Tags: file-uploads, files, ip, site-url

I uploaded my site to a remote server but the links to the image are still pointing to the local version. I have synced the file folders.

What do I need to update to get this to work.

Comment: Easy fix - edit the folder in File Manager > upload directories > edit (the pencil icon)

Comment: Newer versions of EE (3.4+) allow you to use {base_url} and {base_path} for upload directory and upload path to help out with that issue.